# JPQL Filtering child

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa:
What is the best way to filter child object on the parent.
on my below example 
I want Parent objects which has active childs, also wanted only active childs as list with parent

```
  @Query(select distinct p from Parent p inner join p.child c where c.active=:active)

    Page<Parent> getAllPArents(@Param("active") int active);

    @Entity
    Parent{  
      @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      List<Child> child;
    }

    @Entity
    Child{
      @ManyToOne
      Parent parent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending lot of time, I could not find any solution to filter the child while querying the parent.
I decided to change the database structure so that I will be able to query child that I wanted. Added another filed/property that can put child into different categories. When querying child using unique criteria that will give me only the child I needed, also gave me the parent which I needed too.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem and it took me a while to find out how this works. The child list will be filtered when you add `FETCH` after your `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT p FROM Parent p JOIN FETCH p.child c WHERE c.active=:active
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this:
You can use the @Where annotation to filter the childs of a one to many or a many to many relationship.

```
public class Parent {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Parent")
    @Where(clause = "active = 1") //In case of a boolean but it can be a LIKE, a comparator...
    private Set<Child> childs; //This gets filled with pets with a name starting with N

    //getters & setters
}
```